# Simultaneously aggregate a dataset by date, factor and numeric variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I'm sorry this is probably elementary. But I want to aggregate the following dataset, so that for each rating (e.g. Unrated) there is a sum total of beds for that month (e.g. 2015-09-01). In other words, so that I have the total number of Unrated beds for each month in my dataset.

I had once achieved this in dplyr, but it's been a long time since I've used this package. Can anyone help me?

**My data**

```
           Date               Rating Beds Location
1    2015-09-01              Unrated    0 45e484b9
2    2015-09-01              Unrated   16 629f2dbc
3    2015-09-01              Unrated    3 43dc3934
4    2015-09-01              Unrated    3 6ae9569f
5    2015-09-01              Unrated   55 e33a697e
6    2015-09-01              Unrated   54  4caf60f
7    2015-09-01                 Good    7  36bebbb
8    2015-09-01              Unrated   32 4e2c9974
9    2015-09-01                 Good    0 148e5423
10   2015-09-01              Unrated   21 1b207aaf
11   2015-09-01              Unrated   11 a160acba
12   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 5113b802
13   2015-09-01              Unrated    0  c1be28b
14   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   25 fe6eb72a
15   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 c479940d
16   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   28 e953a88d
17   2015-09-01              Unrated   41 15df339b
18   2015-09-01              Unrated   53 19091537
19   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   16 267a1887
20   2015-09-01              Unrated    6 d286b737
21   2015-09-01              Unrated   50 626e6409
22   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 7a29fa0d
23   2015-09-01                 Good   19 58e1cf75
24   2015-09-01              Unrated   25 53b4bc46
25   2015-09-01                 Good    6 7544b5f0
26   2015-09-01                 Good   20 858a642d
27   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 2bff8068
28   2015-09-01              Unrated   17  4323311
29   2015-09-01              Unrated    3 df358985
30   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 49bd617e
31   2015-09-01              Unrated   38 6e49a757
32   2015-09-01              Unrated   36 7242a7f7
33   2015-09-01              Unrated   10 4a6cf0e7
34   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 135f0d16
35   2015-09-01              Unrated   14 83bca8bc
36   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 baba89ca
37   2015-09-01                 Good    0 8823b985
38   2015-09-01              Unrated    0  5bf7d62
39   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 30721e1e
40   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 bf78d89b
41   2015-09-01              Unrated   41 25a69f6d
42   2015-09-01              Unrated   17 f62e2087
43   2015-09-01              Unrated   32 9fa421c7
44   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 7d51b735
45   2015-09-01              Unrated    7  b725abc
46   2015-09-01              Unrated    6 d510e658
47   2015-09-01              Unrated    6 aabf4e94
48   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   20 db2d4d09
49   2015-09-01                 Good    5 3f39dbc4
50   2015-09-01 Requires improvement  171 9e2b91ac
51   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 61cd454a
52   2015-09-01              Unrated   22 68adddc6
53   2015-09-01              Unrated   16 d2d90bc4
54   2015-09-01              Unrated   17 fa283969
55   2015-09-01                 Good    8 b795fb1a
56   2015-09-01                 Good   28 fc7844e7
57   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 a5bb0415
58   2015-09-01                 Good    4 fc4e02d4
59   2015-09-01                 Good   12 7d094614
60   2015-09-01              Unrated    0  79e5f72
61   2015-09-01              Unrated   51 5e1978f6
62   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 b5ccc07a
63   2015-09-01              Unrated    2 2e80ec71
64   2015-09-01              Unrated   20 6d0bb90e
65   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 d28fd369
66   2015-09-01              Unrated   13 6f113881
67   2015-09-01              Unrated   12 dea8a45f
68   2015-09-01              Unrated   24 16c14942
69   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 75363d75
70   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 f78181a4
71   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   39  4cdbafb
72   2015-09-01              Unrated   23 5c6b1d92
73   2015-09-01              Unrated   14 2ace8611
74   2015-09-01 Requires improvement    4 85af25cb
75   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 845278ae
76   2015-09-01              Unrated   79 69b8d20f
77   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 cdf7bd36
78   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 f52e1d4d
79   2015-09-01                 Good   36 ef36da57
80   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   30 c6c27558
81   2015-09-01           Inadequate   38 2d09c93c
82   2015-09-01              Unrated    6 8da74128
83   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 2a9a8672
84   2015-09-01              Unrated   40 7c6c5d2c
85   2015-09-01              Unrated   35 5da6b983
86   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 eabfc9cb
87   2015-09-01              Unrated   20 1285867f
88   2015-09-01           Inadequate   67 b955e0e4
89   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 2b3b1949
90   2015-09-01              Unrated   17 c4e9f3d9
91   2015-09-01              Unrated   26 bc728011
92   2015-09-01              Unrated    6 4b8c2f95
93   2015-09-01                 Good   36 7210439f
94   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 5a70ba54
95   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   40 2c7b4798
96   2015-09-01                 Good   23 f5091d13
97   2015-09-01 Requires improvement   49 2ca5eaaa
98   2015-09-01              Unrated   20 6675bb2a
99   2015-09-01              Unrated    0 86ab3cc2
100  2015-09-01                 Good   40 d5e4de76
101  2015-09-01              Unrated    6 f65a793e
102  2015-09-01 Requires improvement    3 f86d7c21
103  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 41f13e3c
104  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 644c8c71
105  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 22183b7f
106  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 734c6e64
107  2015-09-01              Unrated   32 bddda6e3
108  2015-09-01              Unrated    6 f2ad8f69
109  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 49e1c0c1
110  2015-09-01              Unrated   44 38d19478
111  2015-09-01                 Good   39 4ccf3a13
112  2015-09-01                 Good   89 c001ea34
113  2015-09-01              Unrated   31 96c08e89
114  2015-09-01                 Good    5 8ce65e3a
115  2015-09-01              Unrated    9 e278aa1a
116  2015-09-01              Unrated   60 9bb94812
117  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 5efe62c9
118  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 3a2fed84
119  2015-09-01              Unrated   25 5886a8c9
120  2015-09-01           Inadequate    0 aabe6918
121  2015-09-01                 Good    3 d06aed1f
122  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 bc5bd712
123  2015-09-01 Requires improvement   32 e79446fc
124  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 31e976cf
125  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 b968ef82
126  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 a7467b07
127  2015-09-01                 Good    3  b9844b4
128  2015-09-01              Unrated   40 18fa7cb5
129  2015-09-01 Requires improvement   71 cd0a7ff1
130  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 9d06456a
131  2015-09-01              Unrated   51 7d4180bc
132  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 b424a6f9
133  2015-09-01              Unrated    4 bc1de893
134  2015-09-01              Unrated    4 d86ebae5
135  2015-09-01              Unrated    8 be7d1a8b
136  2015-09-01              Unrated   83 437b01c9
137  2015-09-01                 Good    7 d8a05891
138  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 a5590e37
139  2015-09-01              Unrated    3 5d7ceb81
140  2015-09-01              Unrated    8 4efb2f5b
141  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 dadd8bcb
142  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 13a7c1e9
143  2015-09-01                 Good  108 1a7b9a9d
144  2015-09-01              Unrated   22 83ef3150
145  2015-09-01          Outstanding    0 dacf909f
146  2015-09-01              Unrated   33 958bc5cd
147  2015-09-01              Unrated   33 c8aef73b
148  2015-09-01              Unrated   24 b3385194
149  2015-09-01              Unrated   13 c25afcb6
150  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 6c38d98a
151  2015-09-01              Unrated    3 70ee2e0d
152  2015-09-01                 Good   56 61a1a0b3
153  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 7ae48b88
154  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 df466424
155  2015-09-01              Unrated   20 77c1e39e
156  2015-09-01              Unrated    0 882a09bd
157  2015-09-01              Unrated   66 d6785dd7
158  2015-09-01              Unrated   17 8a50580b
159  2015-09-01              Unrated    3 70f85321
160  2015-09-01                 Good   18 89eb731a
161  2015-09-01              Unrated    9 e1043653
162  2015-09-01              Unrated    8 29f25178
163  2015-10-01              Unrated    7 86ad617d
164  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   80 f3b6e911
165  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 45912a07
166  2015-10-01                 Good   34 643d74d8
167  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 dd95a451
168  2015-10-01              Unrated   19  9ee819d
169  2015-10-01              Unrated   38 3c89db00
170  2015-10-01                 Good    3  8e0b5c2
171  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 11c9955d
172  2015-10-01              Unrated    5 6ee25b5f
173  2015-10-01              Unrated    6 13661924
174  2015-10-01                 Good   30 118abe12
175  2015-10-01                 Good    7 5e67147d
176  2015-10-01                 Good    0 97354815
177  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 f50cac8c
178  2015-10-01           Inadequate   32 8ba58623
179  2015-10-01              Unrated   25 bbf2d265
180  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 fbbab75f
181  2015-10-01 Requires improvement    0 42a7c068
182  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   52 977dbb95
183  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   70 1f1cb3de
184  2015-10-01              Unrated   60 1c9342ae
185  2015-10-01              Unrated    2 b7872e7d
186  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 a8e6d532
187  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 f218b560
188  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 3043fcf2
189  2015-10-01              Unrated   70 55d363e8
190  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 f08c491b
191  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 8e3e0c2f
192  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 802ac892
193  2015-10-01           Inadequate   40 29beacd3
194  2015-10-01              Unrated    4 6725083b
195  2015-10-01                 Good   10 ca2e814a
196  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   58 bbfe3549
197  2015-10-01              Unrated   16 b8e19e7d
198  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 4d611794
199  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 ba6b077b
200  2015-10-01                 Good   10 b4cce423
201  2015-10-01              Unrated    4 144f96d6
202  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   30 bd4de9a6
203  2015-10-01              Unrated   23 a58c0e52
204  2015-10-01              Unrated   36 9333a091
205  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 2b05dff0
206  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 e1440863
207  2015-10-01 Requires improvement    6 e0854142
208  2015-10-01              Unrated   68 8c55f5b7
209  2015-10-01              Unrated    6 303532ae
210  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 74645b95
211  2015-10-01                 Good    3 3184d7e0
212  2015-10-01              Unrated   63 795f671c
213  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   40 151d6def
214  2015-10-01              Unrated   70 2d8f975e
215  2015-10-01                 Good   15 9417d3d0
216  2015-10-01              Unrated   25 f0cf2521
217  2015-10-01              Unrated   40 beaeb079
218  2015-10-01                 Good    0 69b0bbfb
219  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   60 533f4d4b
220  2015-10-01              Unrated   10 7d6aca3f
221  2015-10-01                 Good    0 79092e8f
222  2015-10-01                 Good   46 42649252
223  2015-10-01              Unrated    5 bcae9c41
224  2015-10-01              Unrated   23 6913c924
225  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 b9fae033
226  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 3f092b9a
227  2015-10-01              Unrated   26 5f896dca
228  2015-10-01              Unrated    4 85c66604
229  2015-10-01              Unrated    4 74a79cf5
230  2015-10-01              Unrated   36 cabda90a
231  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 b7a6401c
232  2015-10-01              Unrated   24 b4cd5a59
233  2015-10-01                 Good   41 658b6e7e
234  2015-10-01                 Good   50 20e5441a
235  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 a13ecb6d
236  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 cf00c8b0
237  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 9c085f67
238  2015-10-01              Unrated   48  62a98b4
239  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 2dcad632
240  2015-10-01              Unrated    5 8fcb278c
241  2015-10-01                 Good    0  72ac8d9
242  2015-10-01              Unrated   30 6f6d6d47
243  2015-10-01              Unrated   28  f0f0c26
244  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   80 258e27b7
245  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 17a0ad46
246  2015-10-01              Unrated   25 e5594831
247  2015-10-01                 Good    0 5fbf6308
248  2015-10-01 Requires improvement   45 e45ea462
249  2015-10-01              Unrated   22 412ab7ed
250  2015-10-01              Unrated    0 1bcc654c
```

Comment: Something like `df %>% group_by(Date, Rating) %>% summarise(SUM = sum(Beds))`

Comment: Thanks, but that just gives me a single variable and value. What I need is a total Bed count for each Rating by each month.

Comment: That's not possible, because we're grouping by 2 variables and that should return one value for each combination.

Comment: This is what happens in my editor:

> test2 %>% group_by(Date, Rating) %>% summarise(SUM = sum(Beds))
    SUM
1 89771

Comment: Seems like it completely ignores the grouping. Any warnings? Maybe you're using an old `dplyr` version? Can't think of anything else.

Comment: Issue was I hadn't loaded in tidyverse = *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(dplyr)    

data %>%
  group_by(Date, Rating) %>%
  summarise(sum_beds = sum(Beds))
```

Comment: Just results in a single variable and value: sum_beds = 89771

Comment: The `group_by` function should actually give you a splitted output depending on the grouping variables.

Comment: Are you sure that you loaded the correct package? Maybe try loading `library(tidyverse)`. This loads all required packages.

Comment: [This](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/summarise) definately states that it will give you one line per group.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df$Month <- month(as.Date(df$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) #create a separate month column
df_aggregate <- df %>%
                group_by(Month, Rating) %>%
                summarise(Tot_Beds = sum(Beds, na.rm = T)) %>%
                filter(Rating == "Unrated")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr) #Load dplyr package
library(lubridate) #great package for handling dates

dat %>%
  #filter(Rating == "Unrated") #use this if just interested in Unrated books (wasn't sure)
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date),  #Use lubridate to convert to date format
    Month_name = month(Date, label=T, abbr=F), #Use lubridate to extract month part as number
    Month_numb = month(Date) #Use lubridate to extract month part as number
         ) %>%
  group_by(Rating, Month_name, Month_numb) %>% #group by each column you want to result cut by
  summarise(total = sum(Beds)) %>% #aggregation
  arrange(Month_numb, Rating) %>% #sort results
  select(-Month_numb) #remove month number column
```

Here's a solution that uses most of the verbs in dplyr to help you remember.